# Java Heroku application run locally with foreman

Tags: java, heroku, foreman

I'm following the "Getting Started with Java on Heroku" guide at
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java
I follow the steps till I deploy and execute succesfully the application downloaded from GitHub.
When I try to execute it locally on Windows XP with the command

```
foreman start web
```

I get the error:

```
    web.1  | started with pid 3388
    web.1  | Error: Could not find or load main class Main
    web.1  | exited with code 1
    system | sending SIGKILL to all processes
```

My Procfile is:

```
web:    java %JAVA_OPTS% -cp target\classes:target\dependency\* Main
```

And

```
>echo %JAVA_OPTS%
-Xms256m -Xmx512m
```

Can anyone suggest me how to solve?

Comment: show your project structure..!

Comment: it is only the Main file, it is a "from scratch" project downloaded from GitHub

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quotes and semicolon

```
web: java %JAVA_OPTS% -cp target\classes;"target\dependency\*"  Main
```

Comment: are you editing your **Procfile** to look like the above? If you have a separate file for Windows, like I have, you need to specify it when starting foreman. 'foreman start web --procfile=Procfile.win'

Comment: `web:    java -Xms256m -Xmx512m -cp target\classes:"target\dependency\*" Main` this is my Procfile.win and I run it with `foreman start web --procfile=Procfile.win` and I get the same error in the original question.

Comment: try changing the colon to a semi colon

Comment: Note that if `%JAVA_HOME%` is not set, this can fail (because it thinks "%JAVA_HOME%" is the class name.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue while running through the https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java tutorial.

After tinkering with some of these answers I discovered that step six at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#define-a-procfile tells the answer.

> When you see instructions to run your app with foreman, append an extra -f Procfile.windows flag to ensure your Windows-specific Procfile is picked up. For example: foreman start web -f Procfile.windows

Once I switched to the foreman start web -f Procfile.windows command, everything worked smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with java-getting-stared app downloaded from heroku server. Changing to ";" works on Windows.  Still need ":" on heroku linux server.